# pass textbox values of one page to html template of another page

Tags: asp.net

i have some textboxes.. when 'preview' button is clicked it goes to another page, preview.aspx which contains an html template.. i need to replace the textbox entered values given in the first page inside the template of preview.aspx.. how will i code it using asp.net? The html template is

**preview.aspx**

*From:  
                                                    [mg-from]

                                                    To:    
                                                    [mg-to]

                                                    Subject:
                                                    [mg-subject]*

need to replace [mg-from] with txtfrom.text of the first page......how will i code it using asp.net ....... pls help me ....

Comment: Even worst, *you* are the one who posted the previous question.

Comment: This is pretty much the basics of ASP.NET or any other programming language. If you don't have a clue on what's that about, I suggest you go read some tutorial. Or, if you've done that already, tell us what have you tried so far.

Comment: in the first page's button click i wrote                    protected void btnpreview_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("CommunicationPreview.aspx?mg-to=" + Server.UrlEncode(txtto.Text), true);

    }             and in the next page, preview.aspx, i wrote........                                               protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string to = Request.QueryString["mg-to"];   
    }  
}        its not working... can u correct my code plsssss